# Alexa Skill - NodeJS , Doing an API call with request and callback is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an Alexa skill, In one of my intents I am doing a get reques using request libraries. I am passing a callback function to handle the response, however if I do responsebuilder.speak within callback function it doesnt work. If I put the responsebuilder.speak outside the callback it works, but it will get executed before my response is ready.

On this i am getting below error:
                            "message": "SpeechletResponse was null"
It makes sense, since i would think this needs to be out of the callback function, but then how can I make alexa speak call response after it is completed if i cannot make it within the callback, I have tried similar above using .then on request-promise.

```
const myTestIntent_Handler =  {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'getPsGames' ;
    },
        handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
        let sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        let say = 'Hola desde prueba ';
        var finalstr = '';

        req(options2, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                console.log(error + ' ' + response.statusCode);

                say = 'response valido';

                return responseBuilder
                .speak('response valido desde callback')
                .reprompt('try again, ' + say)
                .getResponse();

                console.log('final del callback');
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked using explicit promises,  so i have one basic question,  doing some code inside request. Then would not work as a promise?

Comment: async/await are you best friends. check my code here: https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/ba0c8e5af0491a6cb88c39bd7cd5c0c7

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rodolfo welcome to SO.

You can make your handle async and wait until the promise is returned. Then you return the result back to Alexa. Here's an example:

```
const getPsGames = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
        handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'getPsGames');
 },
 async handle(handlerInput) {
    let say = 'Hola desde prueba ';
    await getData(url)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            say = 'response valido';
           })
          .catch((err) => {console.log(err)}
    let response = handlerInput.responseBuilder
    return response
        .speak(say)
        .getResponse();
  }
}

const getData = function (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = url.startsWith('https') ? require('https') : require('http');
    const request = client.get(url, (response) => {
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
        reject(new Error('Failed with status code: ' + response.statusCode));
      }
      const body = [];
      response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
      response.on('end', () => resolve(body.join('')));
    });
    request.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked using explicit promises, so i have one basic question, doing some code inside request. Then would not work as a promise?

Comment: Yes you can perform other functions inside the promise but at the end you have to return the response to Alexa from outside the promise.

Comment: So, if i have a nodens wrapper that does wraper.games(x,y).then(){}, i still need to return the new promise to alexa?

Comment: Yes, Alexa needs a response after all of your functions have finish.

Answer (score 0):

The request handler needs to `async` and then you can `await` for the response and reply back.

```
const req = require("request");
const apiRequest = () => {
  const options2 = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: "http://libgen.io/json.php?ids=1,2&fields=Title,Author,MD5" //sample request
  };
  let say = "Hola desde prueba ";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req(options2, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(error + " " + response.statusCode);

        say = "response valido";

        resolve(say);
      }
    });
  });
};
const myTestIntent_Handler = {
   canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "getPsGames"
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const data = await apiRequest();
    const speechText = data;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked using explicit promises, so i have one basic question, doing some code inside request. Then would not work as a promise?